# How to use web.config to overwrite redirect rule for a file with same name but different extension?

Tags: windows, iis, web-config

I have an existing web.config file to redirect a page titled privacy.asp to privacy (without the .asp extension). It works as it should.

I now have a client who had a file privacy.html and I want to send a httpResponseStatus of permanent, that being /privacy.

Here is what I tried but when pulling up the privacy.html it resolves with the .html extension but the actual page is that of the .asp.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

<location path="privacy.html">
<system.webServer>
<httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="/privacy/" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
</system.webServer>
</location>


<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
<rules>
<rule name="privacy" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^privacy" />
<action type="Rewrite" url="privacy.asp" />
</rule>
</rules>
</system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use below rewrite rule:

```
<rule name="privacy" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="privacy.html$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="privacy" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="rewrite rule" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="privacy$" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="privacy.asp" appendQueryString="false" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
            </rule>
```

[image]

Note: do not forget to remove the location path and old URL rewrite rule.

Rregards,
Jalpa

Comment: Thank you Jalpa, I tried your code and it takes me to a 404 error, page not found. It should resolve to https://www.somedomain.com/privacy/

Any idea why?

Comment: I changed your code to have this - match url="^privacy" and it seemed to work.

Comment: If your issue solved then please mark the post as an answer. This will help other people who face the same issue.